# How to compare two passwords in flask

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

How i can compare two passwords in flask? And where i need to do that: in class or in request.method == "POST"? Thanks!

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label='E-mail', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=5, max=35), validators.Email()
    ])
    password = StringField(label='Password', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=6, max=10)
    ])
    password_confirm = StringField(label='Password confirm', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=6, max=10)
    ])

    def validate_name(form, field):
        if len(field.password.data) != len(field.password_confirm.data):
            raise ValidationError('Passwords must be equal')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the example [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/), you can use [`validators.EqualTo()`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#wtforms.validators.EqualTo).

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label='E-mail', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=5, max=35), validators.Email()
    ])
    password = StringField(label='Password', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=6, max=10),
        validators.EqualTo('password_confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    password_confirm = StringField(label='Password confirm', validators=[
        validators.Length(min=6, max=10)
    ])
```

Note that you should probably also be using `PasswordField` instead of `StringField`.